# Referencing an Imported Database In a Shared View

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a feeling I know the answer to this question but I don't like it, so I'm hoping somewhere out there can save me from a massive refactor. Here goes.

My Snowflake project is made up of two key databases:

1. external_sales_data_share - an imported database provided by another Snowflake account
2. client_facing_database - an internally owned and local database

The `client_facing_database` contains a View that leverages data from `external_sales_data_share`. For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SECURE VIEW client_facing_database.external.data.sales_data AS
SELECT 
col1 field_1,
col3 field_2
FROM external_sales_data_share.data.sales_data
where client_id = xxxx;
```

The View works as expected, no problems there. However, when I attempt to share the View with my client I am unable to because my View references an imported database.

```
//Create Share    
CREATE OR REPLACE SHARE CLIENT_SHARE;

// Allow share to access the database and schema of the views    
grant usage on database client_facing_database to share CLIENT_SHARE;
grant usage on schema client_facing_database.data to share CLIENT_SHARE;
```

The above works fine. When I try to add the specific view to the share is when I receive an error.

```
// Command to add View to share
grant select on view client_facing_database.data.sales_data to share CLIENT_SHARE;


// Error returned
"A view or function being shared cannot reference objects from other databases."
```

I understand that the above error is expected and that I should `grant reference_usage` to my share so that it is allowed to read from tables being leveraged in my View. However, the following command, which I believe is correct returns an error.

```
 // Command to allow the share access to the reference database (which is share/imported)
 grant reference_usage on database external_sales_data_share to share CLIENT_SHARE;

 // The error message returned
 "Granting individual privileges on imported database is not allowed. Use 'GRANT IMPORTED PRIVILEGES' instead."
```

Digging into the Snowflake documentation it appears as if what I'm trying to do is not possible, since their suggestion of `GRANTING IMPORTED PRIVILEGES` is done at the role, not the share level.

SO.... what are my questions?

1. Am I indeed correct that one cannot share a View that references an
   imported database?
2. Is there a work-around for using an imported database in a View that will be shared?

Thanks all for the help!

Comment: Is it possible to request that the provider of the imported database share it out to your customer, as well?  It's not possible to share a share, but it is possible to share a database to more than one account.

Comment: You might be having more luck with this on Snowflake Native Apps with this: 
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/native-apps/preparing-data-content#:~:text=similar%20SQL%20commands.-,Referencing%20Objects%20That%20Exist%20Outside%20the%20Application%20Package,-%C2%B6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're correct that you cannot share a share. That is stated in the limitations section for Data Consumers below: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-share-consumers.html#general-limitations-for-shared-databases
2. I suppose you'd have to create a table to a local database, populate it with data that you consume and share that table instead